# Incorporating Recaptcha Email Form Into Existing Django Project

Tags: django, email, gmail, recaptcha

I would like to incorporate an email form with Google Recaptcha similar or identical to this:

https://github.com/maru/django-contact-form-recaptcha

Into this existing django github project:

https://github.com/justdjango/video-membership

Where a website visitor could send emails to a Gmail account that I own directly from the form.

I edited the code from the video membership github project to include a contact page for this purpose.

How can this be accomplished?

video-membership-master/courses/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import ContactPageView

app_name = 'courses'

urlpatterns = [
    path('contact/', ContactPageView.as_view(), name='contact')
]
```

video-membership-master/courses/views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class ContactPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'contact.html'
```

video-membership-master/courses/templates/contact.html:

```
{% extends 'courses/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Contact</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you taken a look at this: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/21/how-to-add-recaptcha-to-django-site.html ?

Comment: @Daniel Homes No I have not. I want to start by setting up a contact email form using this existing github project but I am having a lot of trouble trying to even do that part.

Comment: My suggestion would be to get something working standalone, and then once you understand a bit better how it works, you may have better insight on how to make it part of that existing project.